# Gradient descent implementation of logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, gradient-descent

## Objective

Seeking for help, advise why the gradient descent implementation does not work below.

## Background

Working on the task below to implement the logistic regression.

[image]

## Gradient descent

Derived the gradient descent as in the picture.

`Typo fixed as in the red in the picture.` 
The cross entropy log loss is $- \left [ylog(z) + (1-y)log(1-z)   \right ]$
[image]

Implemented the code, however it says incorrect.

```
import numpy as np  


def LogitRegression(arr):
  # code goes here
  x = arr[0]
  y = arr[1]
  a = arr[2]
  b = arr[3]

  z = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-a * x - b))
  lr = 1.0

  a = a - x * (z-y)
  a = np.round(a, decimals=3)
  b = b - (z-y)
  b = np.round(b, decimals=3)
  
  return ", ".join([str(a), str(b)])

# keep this function call here 
print(LogitRegression(input()))
```

[image]

If I reverted the sign of the gradient update, it works. However, not sure why.

```
  # a = a - x * (z-y)
  a = a + x * (z-y)
  a = np.round(a, decimals=3)

  # b = b - (z-y)
  b = b + (z-y)     
  b = np.round(b, decimals=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loss function, in the image, has a minus sign in the wrong spot. The loss you should be minimizing is $-\left[ y \log z + (1-y) \log (1-z) \right]$. You can show that this is correct by writing down the negative log-likelihood of a Bernoulli random variable.

After you fix the error in the loss equation, you'll need to fix the error in the equations for the gradient updates. You missed a minus sign in the relationship between $L, z, w$ and $a$.